# How to use simple quotes in strings using the command "insert into" on pgAdmin III

Tags: sql, pgadmin

I've made a Java code that reads a text document and returns me a list of sql commands (`insert into`) that I copy and paste on pgAdmin III so it can insert the data read in its database.

As you know, the `insert into` comand uses simple quotes to wrap string values, as it follows:

```
insert into table (description) values ('text from the .txt');
```

The thing is, some descriptions come with simple quotes in its text, and so, it makes pgAdmin understand those as the end of the string:

```
insert into table (description) values ('this is a description where ' this simple quote messes up the command');
```

I also have to do the same with Java expressions, like:

```
if(Currentline.charAt(i) == ''' ){ ... }
```

So I can fix the entire problem.

I think, probably, there is a simples way to solve that. Does anybody knows how to do it? Basically, how to make the pgAdmin incorporate this character to the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is how to escape special characters. Therefore, you have to escape `'` with `'` which means that you would end with `''`, being your insert like this:

```
insert into table (description) 
values ('this is a description where '' this simple quote messes up the command');
```

Edit: since you updated your question with the java code. For java you also need to escape your special character, in this case with `\`. Your code would be:

```
if(Currentline.charAt(i) == '\'' ){ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked in pgAdmin. Do you know how to do it similar in Java, as I now described in the end of the question?

Comment: @ThiagoResende, I updated my answer for the java details